# URL sometimes appended with jsessionid Grails / Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

Sometimes Spring Security appends a `jsessionid` to the end of my URL.  Wouldn't bother me so much if it happened all the time or never, but it seems almost random.  I'm wondering why this is happening and if it has anything to do with remember me not working correctly with LDAP?

`http://localhost:8080/myapplication/login/auth;jsessionid=A07D52CB78DB999947F3EED1917D60F6`

Comment: I see this even without LDAP. I think it is related to some browser bugs, which prevent setting cookie without redirecting to another URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSESSIONID is created by tomcat (or other web container, see [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets11.html)), it's not from Spring Security. JSESSIONID is the unique id of the http session, used at situation when application uses session (put/read some data from sesson during request), but there're no session cookie exists. At this case server trying both ways: setup cookie and append parameter to all links.

Mostly it's because:

- first request from browser (no cookie at all)
- browser has sent invalid sessionid (for example when server was restarted, and existing session became invalid)

And during such request session was used on server side (and was created new session).

*PS I'm not sure that it can be related to LDAP auth issue*

Comment: Good to know.  Being able to eliminate this helped me narrow down the cause of my main problem.  Thanks!